# In Perl, how do I detect whether a (tied) array is empty without looking at its size?

Tags: arrays, perl, tie

I have been tinkering with the idea of hiding some implementation
details of an IPC mechanism behind a tied array. The goal is to be
able to do something like this on the server side:

```
# setup code here. Client provides a function name, we find
# a function to deal with the request:
my $coderef = lookup($method);
local @_;
tie @_, 'My::IPC';
@ret = &$coderef;
```

The `My::IPC` class will then read serialized objects from a
pipe/socket as needed (triggered through the `SHIFT` or `FETCH`
method).

I would like to provide the authors of the server functions with ways
to write his IPC-accessible functions in a way that he would write
local functions, i.e.:

```
sub f1 {
    while (my $param = shift) {
        ...
    }
}
```

... as well as ...

```
sub f2 {
    my ($foo, $bar, $baz, %flags) = @_;
    ...
}
```

`f1` is intended to be able to deal with streams of data that may be
larger than the amount of RAM available -- as long as each individual
object fits into RAM after deserialization, everything is fine. `f2`
is intended for "simpler" functions where the argument list can be
slurped into RAM.

To support both scenarios, the `TIEARRAY` constuctor and the `SHIFT`,
`FETCH`, and `FETCHSIZE` methods need to be implemented. I consider
that part solved. What bothers me is that I can't seem to find a way
that lets me transmit `undef` values to `f1` because even in list
context, `shift` returns `undef` when used on an empty array.
Something like

```
@params = splice @_, 0, 1;
```

might work here, but that does not exactly look like the obvious
solution to users.

I could solve this by making a slight modification to `f1` and by
implementing `FETCHSIZE` in a way that it returns 1 as long as there
is data available:

```
sub f3 {
    while (@_) {
        my $param = shift;
        ...
    }
}
```

But this would break `f2` because only the first element would get
assigned. Apparently, `FETCHSIZE` needs to provide an accurate value,
but to get that accurate value, the entire array needs to be slurped
into RAM -- which defeats the purpose of iterating over it.

Is there an elegant way to support both a "streaming" model (`f1`,
`f3`) and a more simple function-call-like model (`f2`) with the same
tied array implementation?

Comment: [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::GEn) attempts to provide lazy lists.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays have a length. If your code can't behave like an array, giving it the interface of an array isn't a good idea.

You can get the underlying object using `tied`

```
sub f1 {
   while ( my ($param) = tied(@_)->next() ) {
      ...
   }
}

sub f2 {
   my ($foo, $bar, $baz, %flags) = @_;
   ...
}
```

But avoiding tying something that isn't array-like is probably best.

```
sub f1 {
   my $o = shift;
   while ( my ($param) = $o->next ) {
      ...
   }
}

sub f2 {
   my ($foo, $bar, $baz, %flags) = shift->all;
   ...
}
```

Note that `next` is called in list context, so it has the option of returning an empty list in addition to returning undef, allowing the end of the iteration to be distinguishable from `undef`.